# Sin Resultados En Ejecución de la sentencia SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Mi problema es el siguiente, necesito unos datos básicos como es el nombre, el apellido, la especialidad y la cantidad de calificaciones que ha tenido un estudiante.

**NOTA:** Las calificaciones son **bueno**, **regular** y **malo** y no se califica con números para que tengan presente.

**EJEMPLO**

```
NOMBRE  | APELLIDO | ESPECIALIDAD | CANT
PEPITO  | PEREZ    | MEDICINA     | 10
JUANITO | RAMIREZ  | MEDICINA     | 8
```

**LA SENTENCIA**

```
SELECT 
     estudiante.nom_estudiante
    ,estudiante.ape_estudiante
    ,especialidad.id_especialidad
    ,especialidad.descripcion_especialidad
    ,count(calificaciones.resultado_calificacion) AS cant
FROM estudiantes
INNER JOIN especialidad ON (estudiante.id_especialidad = especialidad.id_especialidad)
INNER JOIN calificaciones ON (estudiantes.id_calificacion = calificacion.id_calificacion)
WHERE especialidad.id_especialidad = 1 --(Ej: "MEDICINA")
GROUP BY estudiante.nom_estudiante
    ,estudiante.ape_estudiante
    ,especialidad.id_especialidad
    ,especialidad.descripcion_especialidad.
```

**EL PROBLEMA**

Los resultados que deseo obtener son por especialidad y así mismo de gran importancia saber cuántas calificaciones ha tenido cada estudiante por esa especialidad.

**AL GRANO**

La especialidad "MEDICINA" tiene 50 estudiantes y la sentencia solo me muestra un resultado, si quito el `count(calificaciones.resultado_calificacion) AS cant` y  `INNER JOIN calificaciones ON (estudiantes.id_calificacion = calificacion.id_calificacion)` me muestras los 50 resultados pero sin la cantidad de calificaciones por cada estudiantes entonces no sé que problema está sucediendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo que un estudiante puede tener o no calificaciones, para este caso lo mejor es usar `LEFT JOIN` al momento de unir las calificaciones a la consulta:

```
SELECT estudiante.nom_estudiante
    ,estudiante.ape_estudiante
    ,especialidad.id_especialidad
    ,especialidad.descripcion_especialidad
    ,count(calificaciones.resultado_calificacion) AS cant
FROM estudiantes
INNER JOIN especialidad ON (estudiante.id_especialidad = especialidad.id_especialidad)
LEFT JOIN calificaciones ON (estudiantes.id_calificacion = calificacion.id_calificacion)
WHERE especialidad.id_especialidad = 1 --(Ej: "MEDICINA")
GROUP BY estudiante.nom_estudiante
    ,estudiante.ape_estudiante
    ,especialidad.id_especialidad
    ,especialidad.descripcion_especialidad
```